# Dyamically Assign JSON Property by Depth

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I would like to assign a variable on a json object by layers of depth. 
For Example:

```
veryDeepTree[branch][branch][branch][branch] = value
```

would be achieved by executing the function:

```
assignByDepth(4, value, branch)
```

Comment: How would the function know what property on each intermediate object to use?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by using a recursive function. Where each iteration of the function goes 1 level deeper until it reaches the desired level to set the value. This is a basic version assuming objects exists with correct depth before calling the function. As it is now, there can be multiple errors if used incorrectly, should be amended to add more error checks.

```js
var veryDeepTree = {
    branch : {
       branch : {
          branch : {
          }
       }
    }
};

function assignByDepth(subTree, currentTreeDepth, objProperty, value){
   if(currentTreeDepth == 1){
      subTree[objProperty] = value;
   }else{
      assignByDepth(subTree[objProperty], --currentTreeDepth, objProperty, value);
   }
}

assignByDepth(veryDeepTree, 3, "branch", {branch:10});
console.log(veryDeepTree);

assignByDepth(veryDeepTree, 4, "branch", 5555);
console.log(veryDeepTree);
```